# Найти и заменить часть кода скомпилированной программы

Tags: c, windows, dll, exe

**Отступление:**

Написал я что-то вроде мода на одну игрушку (платформа - `windows`). Уж очень мне не нравилось, как там обстояли дела с чувствительностью мыши. Просидел я с дабеггером и дизассемблером три дня и наконец-то нашел часть кода, которую требовалось изменить.

Я заменил часть кода одной функции и поместил туда код подгрузки своей `dll` и вызова ее функции. Сама `dll` имеет лишь одну подобную функцию:

```
__declspec(export) void mod_some_values(float *value1_ptr ...etc);
```

Из `.exe`-шника игры я подгружаю ее, вызываю (благо игра 64-битная, работают windows x64 calling conventions), а после измененные значения записываю в регистры `xmm3` и `xmm2`. Все вроде хорошо и вроде все работает, но что делать, если обновить игрульку...

**Суть вопроса:**

Мне не хотелось бы распространять данный мод как `игра.exe` + `моя.dll`. Скорее как `патчер.exe` + `моя.dll`. Я, конечно, могу так сделать и патчить по определенному адресу.

Но если игра обновится? Мало того, что необходимый адрес может поменяться, так еще и регистры могут оказаться другими.

Хотелось бы узнать, может быть существуют уже какие-то созданные до меня средства отслеживания необходимой части кода?

Чтобы я, скажем, мог показать кусок кода, а это "средство" нашло бы мне ближайшие совпадения? (не с точки зрения самих байтиков, а с точки зрения инструкций, которые они обозначают). (Конечно же предположив, что логика работы необходимой функции не изменилась. А сама функция лишь сместилась + мог незначительно измениться ее байткод).

А то очень не хотелось бы пилить свой велосипед. Спасибо.

Comment: При взломе лучше не полагаться на прямые адрес, так как от версии к версии байты сдвигаются. Лучше полагаться на сигнатуры. Если метод не привязан к классу с сигнатурой, то находить его через "частичное" дизассемблирование, находя только call инструкцию, в методах которые можно найти проверяя сигнатуры. Сигнатура - определённая комбинация байт, которую можно найти в программе, и она однозначно укажет вам на нужный кусок.

Comment: @nick_n_a т.е. по сути просто искать `call` функции с сигнатурой, которую имеет необходимая функция? Примерно об этом я и думал. Вот только вполне возможно, что в функции будут использоваться другие инструкции, и даже если ее `c++`-вариант будет неизменным, регистры, которые мне нужны, окажутся другими... Как с этим справиться я пока не знаю

Comment: Есть три-четыре вида call, но обычно компилятры ставят E8. Можно сделать расчёт на все. Память перед использованием нужно проверять или IsBadReadPtr или VirtualQuery.

Comment: @nick_n_a хм. А вот пытаться отследить аргументы, как мне кажется, не вариант. Ибо функция не экспортирована, и там используется обычно `fastcall`, так что бог его знает, как и в каких регистрах будут передаваться аргументы...

Comment: А зачем вам их отслеживать. Меняете call на себя, себе забираете бывший адрес для "емуляции", и вам все аргументы становятся извесны. И по бывшему адресу повторяете вызов, что не сломалось ничего.

Comment: @nick_n_a а. Вы, видимо, не до конца поняли... я изменил лишь часть нужной функции. Процентов 10. Полностью ее выпилить нельзя, ибо она дальше делает еще расчеты. Переписать тоже нельзя, ибо она не чистая. Меняет какие-то глобальные переменные. Вот и получается...

Comment: Перехватив функцию вы 1 - всегда получите управление и знаете её аргументы. 2. Можете её настоящую вызвать. 3. Можно похулиганить ДО вызова настоящей. 4. Можно похулиганить после вызова настоящей. Что ещё нужно для полного счатья? Частичное выполнение? Ну тут простите сложно. Делайте. Готовьте ей стек как функция хочет и передавайте управление используя jmp. Но если туда добавят пару локальных переменных... незнаю... проявите смекалку.